# Eclipse : Import maven project into current workspace location

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Would you guys, please tell me how to import the existing maven project which we have copied from different user into my local and wanted to imported into new workspace not just project view vis but the content of project classes and pom.xml need to copy physically into my new workspace directory.

Means, if my current workspace location is : `C:\ALL-PROJECTS\New-Project\` and my copied location of that project is`C:\Downloads\Copied_Project\` so, i wanted to copy all code from copied loc : **Copied_Project** to my current workspace location : **New-Project**

So that in future i will going to keep one copy of it, going to delete copied location. And that will be more manageable in future onces we have many projects like this.

Comment: go into File->import->Maven->Existing Maven Projects->enter your project path where pom.xml is present then click finish. you dont need to copy anything in work-space just give you project path to eclipse it will take maven project.

Comment: @Afgan I do agreed on it, but consider the case where i wanted to have copied existing maven project into my current workspace physical location then ?

Comment: Do you want make a clone of your project in you eclipse work space ?

Answer (score 2):

```
File > Import > General > Existing Projects into Workspace
```

Click Next

Select root directory of project

Check project in `Projects` lists and check option `Copy projects into workspace`

Click Finish

Answer (score 0):

Just copy that project to ur project location and import that from same location

Answer (score 0):

You can import as usual but you have to leave all the meta data like .classpath and .project etc files because you changed the location of your project so these files having the physical location path which is already changed by you. So it will not work.

Else you just searched the old location inside all the files and replace with location and import into eclipse or IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for copying projects between different Eclipse workspaces is to export the project as a jar file

You can then take that exported project .jar file and import it into your new workspace using the Import Existing Projects into Workspace and selecting your archive (.jar) file

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about other IDE But in eclipse this is how it is done

copy the project folder into your workspace folder 
Make sure the project folder has `pom.xml` immediately under it .

open eclipse . your copied project will not be found unless you import it . 
So Go to

```
File->import->Maven->Existing maven project
```

Then choose your project folder from explorer and follow the procedure your IDE takes you through

Finally right click on the project Go to `maven->update project`